# How to access a model from another controller in Ember

Tags: ember.js, firebase, emberfire

This is a novice question: I'm creating a new Chapter record in the Store (Ember-data). I want to add the Chapter ID to the User.chapters property of the User Model record.

```
App.Book = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  icon: DS.attr('string'),
  description: DS.attr('string'),
  createdDate: DS.attr('date'),
  chapters: DS.hasMany('chapter', { inverse: 'book', async: true}),
  bookAssignments: DS.hasMany('bookAssignment', {async: true}),
  user: DS.belongsTo('user', { inverse: 'books', async: true} ),
});

App.Chapter = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  description: DS.attr('string'),
  source: DS.attr('string'),
  book: DS.belongsTo('book', { inverse: 'chapters', async: true}),
  user: DS.belongsTo('user', { inverse: 'chapters', async: true} )
});

App.User = DS.Model.extend({
  uid: DS.attr('string'),
  displayName: DS.attr('string'),
  firstName: DS.attr('string'),
  lastName: DS.attr('string'),
  books: DS.hasMany('condition', { inverse: 'user', async: true}),
  chapters: DS.hasMany('statistic', { inverse: 'user', async: true}),
});
```

I have created a Session object that I inject into the routes and controllers

```
App.Session = Ember.Object.extend({
  user: null,
  userID: '',
});

Ember.Application.initializer({
  initialize: function (container, application) {
    App.register('session:main', App.Session.create(), { instantiate: false, singleton: true });
    // Add `session` object to route to check user
    App.inject('route', 'session', 'session:main');
    // Add `session` object to controller to visualize in templates
    App.inject('controller', 'session', 'session:main');
  }
});
```

However, the Session object is not a Model and could not be saved to the Store with the Save() method:

```
user.save()
```

Another option that I explored is to access the User record from the User Route Model Hook. The user route:

```
App.UserRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    //var session = this.get('session');
    var user = '';
    var _isAutheticated = this.isAutheticated;
    var store = this.store;
    var _firebase = new Firebase("https://dynamicslife.firebaseio.com");
    _firebase.onAuth(function(authData) { 
      if (authData) {
        _isAutheticated = true;
        console.log('user authenticated with Firebase', authData.uid);  
        user = store.find('user', authData.uid).then(function(_user) {
          console.log('user found', _user);
          return _user;
        }, function(error) {
        // user does not exist or some other error
        console.log('please log again');     
      });
      } else if (error) {
        _isAutheticated = false;
        console.log('failled login attempt', error);
      }
    }); //end authWithOAuthPopup
    console.log('My user2: ', user);
    //this.set('isAutheticated', _isAutheticated);
    return user;
  }
});
```

I tried Needs to access the User record from the Chapter Controller:

```
App.ChaptersController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({ 
  needs: 'user',
  user: Ember.computed.alias("controllers.user.model"),
});
```

However, User remains not available.

I imaging that my syntax is not correct. I would greatly appreciate if someone could indicate me a proper way to access the User record in a way that it can be modified and saved from the Chapters controller.

The Chapters route is not nested under the User route because the templates are not nested. Should I nest the Chapters Route under the User Route even if the templates are not nested to use ModelFor()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to access a particular record from the chapter model you can do so by using `this.store.find('chapter', record_id)` from the controller, since `store` is available for all controllers (and routes).

If you need to create a new chapter record from the controller you can do `this.store.createRecord('chapter')` and it will give you an empty record to work with.

In this case there will be no need to inject the model directly.

Comment: And how is this model saved afterwards  ?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to inject your session object to all your controllers and/or routes. You will then be able to access it where you need it.

Within the session, create a property called user that will load the user (maybe using the code you put in the route there), link everything to "session.user" in your controller and you should be good to go.

As for your routing question, yes if you want to load the user model from a route, that route should be loaded. Either as the root route or within the route tree.